# Checking the return value of a function into another function

Tags: c

I am quite unsure how I would check the return value of a function into another function.

Essentially, I want to check the return value of `f1` inside `f2`. Depending on return value of `f1`, `f2` will return `count` or `0`.

Inside this `a.c` file I have two functions, as shown below

```
unsigned int count = 0;

bool f1(char *word)
{
    while (...)
    {
        if (...) return false;
        count++;
    }
    return true;
}

unsigned int f2(void)
{
    if (f1 == true) return count;    //<----I know this doesn't make sense, but I'm unsure how to do this
    else return 0;
}
```

In another file, `b.c`, those two functions are called

```
int main()
{
    bool foo1 = f1(word);
    unsigned int foo2 = f2();
}
```

I don't think I should call `f1` again inside `f2` (or should I?), but I know I need to store the return value of `f1` somewhere inside `a.c` without calling it again(?). I tried putting `#include "b.c"` atop `a.c`, so I could just do

```
unsigned int f2(void)
{
    if (foo1 == true) return count;    
    else return 0;
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: You need to pass `foo1` as an argument to `f2()`

Comment: @TomKarzes He's already calling it in `main()`, it shouldn't be called twice.

Comment: @Barmar Look at `f2`.  It countains `if (f1 == true) return count;`  Are you claiming that makes sense?

Comment: @TomKarzes Of course it doesn't make sense. But neither does calling it a second time.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not saying it should be called more than once.  I'm saying that comparison makes no sense and will produce an error.

Comment: But yours is the wrong fix. See my answer.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, I shouldn't have suggested that change as a fix.  It would fix the compiler error, but not the logic problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the return value of `f1` in a global variable.

```
unsigned int count = 0;
bool f1val;

bool f1(char *word)
{
    while (...)
    {
        if (...) {
            f1val = false;
            return f1val;
        }
        count++;
    }
    f1val = true;
    return f1val;
}

unsigned int f2(void)
{
    if (f1val) return count;
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as per instructions, I should not change `f1()` and `f2()` with regards to what I can pass to them. And that I should be only changing `a.c` so I really cannot change anything inside `main` (which is inside `b.c`). But what I can do is make another function inside `a.c`.

Comment: In that case you need to put the value in a global variable.

Comment: No, global variables like this make the program *less* flexible, because `f2()` can only be used for `f1()`, not with other functions that modify different variables.